# personal.newAccount("mypassword") stops the server when i create two accounts consecutively in local privatenet

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, memory

```
personal.newAccount("mypassword")
```

stops the server when i try to create two accounts one after the another.

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0],"mypassword");
```

same happens when I try unlock account. More than one request geth console causes the server to stop.
Is it possible that the `personal` API is the cause or could it be a memory related problem? The logs show `fatal error : out of memory`; But if i do this operation after few minutes of time gap it works fine. Executing consecutively is the problem. Mining and transactions are working fine.
what could be the reason behind such behavior?

Comment: checked, don't have the problem on my privnet, what version of geth are you using?

Comment: Geth
Version: 1.5.0-unstable
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.5.1

Comment: While using a Pi, I have observed that creating and unlocking accounts consumes more memory than other commands. It also takes some time (5-10 seconds) for the output. What are your system specs?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, 6 gb RAM, 32 bit OS

Comment: This seems like a bug that should be reported on github. I;m not sure we'll be able to help you here.

Answer (score -1):

You have the development version of Geth, where this bug seems to happen, downgrade to `Geth 1.4.10` like shown here:

https://m.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4tovvr/how_do_i_downgrade_from_geth_15_to_1410/

Comment: same problem is there with 1.4.9 as well

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.